# Conditional cdf

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I want to know that how conditioning will affect the CDF of dependent random variables. More specifically, let's suppose,
$\Gamma_R={g\over A}$ and $\Gamma_D={g\cdot h\over B}$, where $g$ and $h$ are exponential random variables and $A$ and $B$ are some constant values. I want to find

$$\Pr \{min(\Gamma_R,\Gamma_D)<\gamma\}\quad\quad (1)$$

Since both $\Gamma_R$ and $\Gamma_D$ are statistically dependent because of the common term $g$.

**So my question is:** by conditioning on $g$, does the random variables $\Gamma_R$ and $\Gamma_D$ becomes independent? if yes then can I write eq.1 in the following form 
$$\Pr \{\Gamma_R<\gamma,\Gamma_D<\gamma\}\quad\quad (2)$$
$$\Pr \{g<\gamma A,h<\gamma{B\over g}\}\quad\quad (3)$$

$$=\int_0^\infty F_{\Gamma_R|g}(\gamma) \, \,\,\,\,F_{\Gamma_D|g}(\gamma)\, \,\,\,\,f_{g}(z) \, \,\,\,\,dz\quad\quad (4)$$

If yes then what will be the value of $F_{\Gamma_R|g}(\gamma)$, is it equals to 1? if yes, how? and can I just simply omit it from the above equation?

Any kind of help will be very much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ constants or random variables? What is the _joint_ distribution of $g$ and $h$?  Conditioned on $g=g_0 > 0$, $\Gamma_R = \frac{g_0}{B}$ is a constant or a random variable depending on what $A$ is and so for constant $A$, the event $\{\Gamma_R < \gamma\}$ has _conditional_ probability $0$ or $1$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, Dilip for your kind reply,

Yes, $A$ and $B$ are constants.